# Deserialize multiple json fields in one object field

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm coming from Java environment to python environment and I'm a little bit confuse. I need to consume some events from kafka. I found this way to deserialize json to custom object:

`x = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))`

My problem is that in some events I receive a field `a1` and in other events I receive a field `a2`. I need to map `a1` and `a2` in a single python object field `a`.

Can I do this without writing custom code? Can I use a library that decorates field `a` to know how to deserialize?

Best regards